# p5js is adding div each time when click

Tags: javascript, p5.js

#Hey-PeePs. The issue is happening in p5js:

I have: 1 function(), 1 draw(), 2 sketches(canvas)

Using: Instance Mode

All I want is a gallery! there is an image in thumbnail size, when click goes full-size, which is the reason I have 2 canvases. The following code is working. It  will create a canvas with the thumbnail size of the image and then when I click on it, it will create a DIV which contains the full-screen image.

The issue is, every time I click on the thumbnail, it will create another DIV and it just goes on. How can I set a condition for this? So it will only draw once!

```js
var PictureThumbnail = function(p) {
  let ThumbImage;
  let fullSize;
  
  p.preload = function() {
    ThumbImage = p.loadImage('https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/Coin120.png');
  };

  p.setup = function() {
    var canvas = p.createCanvas(100, 100);
    canvas.parent('#Thumbnail');

    fullSize = createDiv('Full Size Image');
    fullSize.addClass('fullSize');
    fullSize.hide();
  };

  p.draw = function() {
    p.image(ThumbImage, 0, 0, 700, 70);
    if (mouseIsPressed) {
      if ((p.mouseX > 0) && (p.mouseX < 100) && (p.mouseY > 0) && (p.mouseY < 100)) {
        fullSize.show();

        let sketch2 = function(p) {
          p.setup = function() {
            p.createCanvas(500, 500);
            p.background(255);
          }
        };
        new p5(sketch2, window.document.getElementById('fullSize'));
      }
    }
  };
};

let sketch = new p5(PictureThumbnail);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Thumbnail"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The last line of code is the issue.

new p5(sketch2, window.document.getElementById('fullSize'));

Comment: Your code is incomplete and has a number of obvious bugs (see errors in the console when the snippet is run). If you follow best practices for asking StackOverflow questions you won't waste time with this kind of unrelated issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues:

#### 1. Invalid references:

You have several references to global p5.js methods and properties where you should be referencing the instance methods (`createDiv` and `mouseIsPressed`).

#### 2. Action in `draw()` that should be in `mousePressed()`

The way you're using `mouseIsPressed` is flawed. Draw is going to be running repeatedly and `mouseIsPressed` will be `true` over several calls so you're going to be repeatedly creating `sketch2`.

#### 3. Attempt to get an element by id that does not exist

You create a div with the class `'fullSize'` and no `id` and then you attempt to get an element with the `id` `'fullSize'` but no such element exist.

---

Here's a working example:

```js
var PictureThumbnail = function(p) {
  let ThumbImage;
  let fullSize;
  let fullSizeOpen = false;

  p.preload = function() {
    ThumbImage = p.loadImage('https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/Coin120.png');
  };

  p.setup = function() {
    var canvas = p.createCanvas(100, 100);
    canvas.parent('#Thumbnail');

    fullSize = p.createDiv('Full Size Image');
    fullSize.addClass('fullSize');
    fullSize.id('fullSize');
    fullSize.hide();
  };

  p.mousePressed = function() {
    if ((p.mouseX > 0) && (p.mouseX < 100) && (p.mouseY > 0) && (p.mouseY < 100)) {
      if (!fullSizeOpen) {
        fullSizeOpen = true;
        fullSize.show();

        let sketch2 = function(p) {
          p.setup = function() {
            p.createCanvas(500, 500);
            p.background('red');
          }
        };
        new p5(sketch2, window.document.getElementById('fullSize'));
      }
    }
  }

  p.draw = function() {
    p.image(ThumbImage, 0, 0, 700, 70);
  };
};

let sketch = new p5(PictureThumbnail);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Thumbnail"></div>
</body>

</html>
```